# Scene track doesn't get rendered

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I am doing video editing in Blender (version 3.4) and trying to add a scene into my video.
I created a new scene, drawn some things to it and added into my video in channel 1 using the **New > Scene** context menu:

[image: scene creation]

I can see my scene appears in the preview of the video, but when I try rendering the video (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> > Render Animation), the scene is replaced with a black screen. What is causing this? I am also attaching the Blender file where I minimally reproduced this problem: https://files.fm/u/2mkufm7rx.

In the Blender file, there are two scenes: `Scene` and `Drawing`. `Drawing` is the scene where there is a camera and a drawing, in **2D Animation** panel. The camera points to that drawing. `Scene` is where the video editing happens, in the **Video Editing** panel.

Thanks in advance!

My blend file:

[image]

Comment: Pleases share you blend file using Blend-Exchange, https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Phönix64 The file is already attached, but I also uploaded it to blend-exchange. I edited the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is how you set up your scene.

When you run a render and something doesn't go as expected, you should look if there's any error messages anywhere. First in the top left corner of the Render Result view, then in the Info Editor, then in Blender's System console.

Here, you can already see the issue in the Render Result:

[image: error message]

Go in the Properties Editor > View Layer tab and make sure both Combined and Z passes are enabled like so:

[image: passes]

Then the next issue is harder to spot because even the rendered view doesn't allow you to see the issue: you have no lights in your scene. No lights = everything's black.

You could add lamp objects, but in your context, I reckon it would be simpler to go to the Properties Editor > World tab > create a world material with pure white color and a strength of 1. That will light up your scene uniformly.

[image: world shader]

Finally, you might notice at this point that when pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, the result is way darker than what you have when looking at the viewport or the video sequencer.
This is because your editing scene's color management view transform is set to Standard (aka 8bit sRGB), while your drawing scene is in Filmic. Either one is good, but you have to pick one and stick to it if you want unexpected results, as there is no way to override a specific strip's color management.
You can access this setting via the Properties Editor > Render settings tab > Color Management while being on a specific Scene:

[image: color management]

Comment: Hey. A simple "Accept as answer" button doesn't express my gratitude enough. Thank you very much for explaining in a digestible fashion!